# Opening large file

Tags: c, gcc, embedded-linux

I'm trying to open a large file (>5GB) on an embedded linux distribution. 
From the shell I find to have all permissions:

-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     pi       5368709120 Mar 20 23:36 5GB.bin

My code is very simple:

```
    int file;
    file = open(frb_man_r.frb_path, O_LARGEFILE);
    if(file == -1)
      return errno;
```

I found several topics both on other stackoverflow posts and around the web explaining in details how to manage >32bit files, specifically related to LFS like the page [here](http://users.suse.com/~aj/linux_lfs.html)

So I put on my source code the definitions below:

```
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
```

Moreover, i added on my project (which is a library) and all the other related projects this macro:`_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

Now, unfortunately the result of my open call is resulting in errno = 2, which means "No such file or directory"

Somebody knows why?
Regards

Comment: Is this a 32-bit executable or not?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't exactly what what the error indicates?  That is, have you perhaps gotten the filename or path wrong?  If you are using a relative path, are you sure the working directory is correct for that path?

Comment: Try giving it a small file first and see that the code is working.

Comment: in your post, show what exactly is contained in the string `frb_man_r.frb_path`.  The path if absolute will be of the form: `/dir1/dir2/.../dir_n/filname.ext` if file is downstream of calling executable.  A location relative to the executable will be preceded with: `./` (if local, or downstream) or `../` (if file is in an upstream directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare file as int, you're asking the OS to give you a peace of static memory.
Try use pointer, using FILE.

It's how I use I/O in gcc, I used file >30GB with FILE, so i know it works fine

the sintax:

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen(frb_man_r.frb_path,"r");
     if(file == NULL)
         printf("no memory or no file");
```

*file* have all the content of your file;

Comment: yes, thanks! Since I just ctrl c+v his code, I forgot to change. Thanks

Comment: While suggesting using `FILE*` instead of `int` is perfectly right thing, the explanation provided and the assumption it is the root cause is most likely wrong.